# onConfigChanged() NOT called when device orientation changes

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I'm having problems capturing the orientation changes in my app. I want to prevent my app form being restarted when the device is re-orientated.

There are 3 Activities in my app all together (the third being FragmentActivity). The main user interaction is through the FragmentActivity.

I have altered the manifest so that ALL activities have the following attribute:

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

I have also overridden the `onConfigurationChanged()` method in all activities and to see if it is actually getting called I have included a `Log.i()` statement but nothing is ever reported.

I'm currently testing this with the Emulator and orientation changes are reported when I do a CTRL+F12.

> I/ActivityManager(   67): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260
>   loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17
>   seq=10}

Is there something I am mising?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

`Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).`

Comment: I just noticed it works fine on an actual device i.e. no restarts as I expected. Maybe an Emulator problem?

Comment: It means if my app target api level is 16,i should use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" ?

Comment: I have min sdk version 10 and target sdk version 15. Android will not allow me to add screenSize as a configuration change case, and neither it will delegate screen orientation changes to the activity. Changing target sdk version to 10 brings the expected functionality back. Any idea about how I may be able to keep the target version 15, but still be able to capture screen orientation changes? Thanks.